# Get current locale in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, gettext, python-babel

On my website use Flask + Jinja2, and Flask-Babel for translation. The site has two languages (depending on the URL), and I'd want to add a link to switch between them. To do this correctly I need to get the name of the current locale, but I didn't find such function in the docs. Does it exist at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I used this solution: add `get_locale` function, which should be defined anyway, to Jinja2 globals, and then call it in template like any other function.

Comment: How did you add to jinja2 globals? I've tried doing e=Environment, e.globals = {'get_locale':get_locale}

Answer (score 7):

Other answers say that you must implement the babel's `get_locale()` function and that you should add it to Jinja2 globals, but they don't say how. So, what I did is:

I implemented the `get_locale()` function as follows:

```
from flask import request, current_app

@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    try:
        return request.accept_languages.best_match(current_app.config['LANGUAGES'])
    except RuntimeError:  # Working outside of request context. E.g. a background task
        return current_app.config['BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE']
```

Then, I added the following line at my Flask `app` definition:

```
app.jinja_env.globals['get_locale'] = get_locale
```

Now you can call `get_locale()` from the templates.

Answer (score 1):

You are responsible to store the user's locale in your session on database. `Flask-babel` will not do this for you, so you should implement `get_locale` method for `flask-babel` to be able to find your user's locale.

This is an example of `get_locale` from `flask-babel` documentation:

```
from flask import g, request

@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    # if a user is logged in, use the locale from the user settings
    user = getattr(g, 'user', None)
    if user is not None:
        return user.locale
    # otherwise try to guess the language from the user accept
    # header the browser transmits.  We support de/fr/en in this
    # example.  The best match wins.
    return request.accept_languages.best_match(['de', 'fr', 'en'])
```

Comment: Yes, I've implemented such get_locale function, it returns a locale depending on the URL. But how to get active request locale in a Jinja template?